# Непритокманий. Непритокмане. Що це за слова?

Tags: вживання-слів, невідоме-слово

У "Польових дослідженнях з українського сексу" О. Забужко є таке речення:

> ...але вдома, в твоїй бiднiй забембанiй країнi - країнi урядовцiв в
>   обвислих штанях i всiяних лупою пiджаках, оплилих письменникiв,
>   зугарних читати лиш одною мовою, та й з того вмiння нестак-то
>   вжиткуючих, i бистрооких, жучкуватих бiзнесовцiв iз навичками колишнiх
>   комсомольських секретарiв, - все воно якось нi до чого не крiпилося,
>   провисало **непритокмане** й ото хiба тiльки до виливу жовчi дрочило,
>   своєю туманною, зашифрованою в незнайомих iменнях i реалiях
>   недосяжнiстю, натоптуваних домашнiх самоукiв (чомусь незмiнно - на
>   куцих, жокейськи вивернутих ногах: порода така, чи що?), закваснiлих
>   де-небудь в обласнiй публiчнiй бiблiотецi iменi Грьомiна в час, коли
>   ти мала нахабство (чи може, дурне щастя, думалось їм?) вештатися по
>   Гарвардськiй "Вайденер" i де там ще...

Все речення не наводжу, бо воно ще довше, аніж те, що вже процитовано.

Починаю шукати прикметник ["непритокманий"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&rlz=1C1HLDY_enUA785UA785&oq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.2202j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) у ґуґлі й нічого не знаходжу. Вводжу ["непритокмане"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5&rlz=1C1HLDY_enUA785UA785&oq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5&aqs=chrome..69i57.4552j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), як у тексті, знаходить сам лише цей текст.

Що це за слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Щоби відповісти на питання, треба просто відкинути префікс "не-" і пошукати слово "притокманий".

У [російсько-українському академічному словнику 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) і у [Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) знаходимо:

Такі синоніми слова "притокманий":

> 1. (про будівлю) прибудо́ваний, примуро́ваний, пригоро́джений;
> 2. примі́щений, примо́щений, приту́лений, прито́кманий.

І такі варіанти вжитку:

> Чи притокмив ти їх у те «училище?» Шевч. (О. 1962. VI. 6).
>
> І він туди притокманий. НВолын. у.